# Paypal return URL parameters payment_status

Tags: java, google-app-engine, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

i am having return page for paypal response in my project. i am catching response from paypal but i gets different status of payment in response ?

i want all payment_status return by paypal in url..

my code for catching response from paypal is -

```
request.getParameter("payment_status")
request.getParameter("first_name")
request.getParameter("payer_email")
request.getParameter("quantity")
request.getParameter("payment_gross")
request.getParameter("tax")
```

Comment: Please add more context to your question.  It is not possible to understand what is happening in your code with so little information.  What Java code is sending the request and receiving the response from PayPal?

Comment: thanks... I got all paymnet_status return by Paypal on Paypal IPN.